# Package appears in Anaconda prompt but not in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, geopandas

Why does the `geopandas` package appear that it is installed looking via `Anaconda Prompt`, but when looking at `Jupther` it doesn't show up? I have added a comparative image for you to see. What's wrong? I made `pip list` for you to see.

[image]

Using `where`
[image]

Comment: I always install like this: `pip install packagename`

Comment: make sure you're using the same environment in both cases. rather than pip list, use `conda list`. identify which conda environment geopandas and jupyter are in with `where conda`, `where python`, `where pip`, and `where jupyter`. If e.g. jupyter is in base but the active python in your terminal is in `my-env` then that's your issue.

Comment: also, if your issue is with installing geopandas, definitely try installing geopandas with conda, not pip. See [this guide to installing geopandas](/a/54734667/72251100#72251100)

Comment: Thanks @Michael. I inserted in the question a figure with the `where conda`, `where python`, `where pip` and `where jupyther`. Could you please check if there is anything wrong?

Comment: Thanks Antonio. Generally, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - instead, copy the code and output into a [formatted code block](/help/formatting).

Comment: yeah - so you've got (at least) two versions of jupyter and pip installed, and it looks like they're not in the same order, so jupyter would come from your conda env and geopandas is being installed by your system pip. Make sure to use environments and activate them, and make sure your geopandas environment has `ipykernel` installed so jupyter can run a notebook using it.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDelgado I did as you said and it worked and it was also possible to install using `geopandas` doing like this: `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`

Comment: please don't follow people around on SO like this. You can ask a new question, which you did, and if it's not getting enough attention, you probably need to do more work to make it easier for the answerers to work with. [This guide](https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports) gives some good tips & perspective.

Comment: Ok, sorry, thanks for reply e feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate your environment? use `conda activate <name>` to activate it if you didn't.
If you did, what command do you use to install geopandas? Try use `pip install geopandas` and try again.

Comment: would give +1 for this, except `pip install geopandas` gets people in all kinds of trouble, and the OP already suggested they're using conda. the [recommended installation method](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html) for geopandas is `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`.